# Flutter: Find the number of days between two dates

Tags: flutter, date, dart, difference

I currently have a user's profile page that brings out their date of birth and other details. But I am planning to find the days before their birthday by calculating the difference between today's date and the date of birth obtained from the user.

**User's Date of Birth**

[image: User DOB]

And this is today's date obtained by using the [intl package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/intl#-installing-tab-).

**Today's date**

```
I/flutter ( 5557): 09-10-2018
```

The problem I am facing now is, How do I calculate the difference in days of these two dates?

Are there any specific formulas or packages that are available for me to check out?

Answer (score 359, accepted):

You can use the `difference` method provide by `DateTime` class

```
 //the birthday's date
 final birthday = DateTime(1967, 10, 12);
 final date2 = DateTime.now();
 final difference = date2.difference(birthday).inDays;
```

**UPDATE**

Since many of you reported there is a bug with this solution and to avoid more mistakes, I'll add here the correct solution made by @MarcG, all the credits to him.

```dart
  int daysBetween(DateTime from, DateTime to) {
     from = DateTime(from.year, from.month, from.day);
     to = DateTime(to.year, to.month, to.day);
   return (to.difference(from).inHours / 24).round();
  }

   //the birthday's date
   final birthday = DateTime(1967, 10, 12);
   final date2 = DateTime.now();
   final difference = daysBetween(birthday, date2);
```

This is the original answer with full explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67679455/666221

Comment: why it calc +1 on 11PM?

Comment: How to handle/exclude weekdays ?

Comment: Sometimes this method doesn't meet expectations 

`DateTime.parse("2020-01-10 00:00:00.299871").difference(DateTime.parse("2020-01-09 23:00:00.299871")).inDays = 0`.

Comment: The `difference` counts milli- or microseconds between the two points in time, then the `inDays` returns the number of entire "days" (24 entire hours) in that time, rounded down. To count calendar days between two dates, the dates should have the exact same hours/minutes/seconds/milliseconds/microseconds (for example zero) and be UTC days - because some local-time days are 23 or 25 hours long due to daylight savings. Then it works.

Comment: @Developine did you find out any way to exclude weekdays ?

Comment: Yes. @sh0umik. if you can post a question and tag me I will be able to provide answer.

Comment: @Developine is it a long ans ? I don't want to duplicate the question. Can you provide hint on what you did to achieve this ?

Comment: When the difference is less than 24h, it doesn't count as a full day. But I want to know, if the day is today or tomorrow.

Comment: same problem for me @ValentinSeehausen. I guess we can calculate also the hours and do that +1 if necessary. I couldn't find a better way

Comment: This answer is WRONG. Don't use it. I have posted another answer which takes into account the time of the day AND daylight savings.

Answer (score 80):

**The accepted answer is wrong. Don't use it.**

This is correct:

```dart
int daysBetween(DateTime from, DateTime to) {
  from = DateTime(from.year, from.month, from.day);
  to = DateTime(to.year, to.month, to.day);
  return (to.difference(from).inHours / 24).round();
}
```

Testing:

```dart
DateTime date1 = DateTime.parse("2020-01-09 23:00:00.299871");
DateTime date2 = DateTime.parse("2020-01-10 00:00:00.299871");

expect(daysBetween(date1, date2), 1); // Works!
```

---

**Explanation why the accepted answer is wrong:**

Just run this:

```dart
int daysBetween_wrong1(DateTime date1, DateTime date2) {
  return date1.difference(date2).inDays;
}

DateTime date1 = DateTime.parse("2020-01-09 23:00:00.299871");
DateTime date2 = DateTime.parse("2020-01-10 00:00:00.299871");

// Should return 1, but returns 0.
expect(daysBetween_wrong1(date1, date2), 0);
```

Note: Because of daylight savings, you can have a 23 hours difference between some day and the next day, even if you normalize to 0:00. That's why the following is ALSO incorrect:

```dart
// Fails, for example, when date2 was moved 1 hour before because of daylight savings.
int daysBetween_wrong2(DateTime date1, DateTime date2) {
  from = DateTime(date1.year, date1.month, date1.day);  
  to = DateTime(date2.year, date2.month, date2.day);
  return date2.difference(date1).inDays; 
}
```

*Rant: If you ask me, Dart `DateTime` is very bad. It should at least have basic stuff like `daysBetween` and also timezone treatment etc.*

---

**Update:** The package https://pub.dev/packages/time_machine claims to be a port of Noda Time. If that's the case, and it's ported correctly (I haven't tested it yet) then that's the Date/Time package you should probably use.

Comment: it would be great if you send an update to my answer :)

Comment: Instead of rounding, it'd be much cleaner if your `daysBetween` function used the `DateTime.utc` constructor instead.  UTC `DateTime` objects do not observe DST.

Comment: I think @jamesdlin is correct and this returns the correct value: `return DateTime.utc(date1.year, date1.month, date1.day).difference(DateTime.utc(date2.year, date2.month, date2.day)).inDays;`.

Answer (score 13):

Use DateTime class to find out the difference between two dates.

```
DateTime dateTimeCreatedAt = DateTime.parse('2019-9-11'); 
DateTime dateTimeNow = DateTime.now();
final differenceInDays = dateTimeNow.difference(dateTimeCreatedAt).inDays;
print('$differenceInDays');
```

***or***

You can use [jiffy](https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy#-readme-tab-). Jiffy is a date dart package inspired by momentjs for parsing, manipulating and formatting dates.

Example:
**1. Relative Time**

```
Jiffy("2011-10-31", "yyyy-MM-dd").fromNow(); // 8 years ago
Jiffy("2012-06-20").fromNow(); // 7 years ago

var jiffy1 = Jiffy()
    ..startOf(Units.DAY);
jiffy1.fromNow(); // 19 hours ago

var jiffy2 = Jiffy()
    ..endOf(Units.DAY);
jiffy2.fromNow(); // in 5 hours

var jiffy3 = Jiffy()
    ..startOf(Units.HOUR);
jiffy3.fromNow();
```

**2. Date Manipulation:**

```
var jiffy1 = Jiffy()
      ..add(duration: Duration(days: 1));
jiffy1.yMMMMd; // October 20, 2019

var jiffy2 = Jiffy()
    ..subtract(days: 1);
jiffy2.yMMMMd; // October 18, 2019

//  You can chain methods by using Dart method cascading
var jiffy3 = Jiffy()
     ..add(hours: 3, days: 1)
     ..subtract(minutes: 30, months: 1);
jiffy3.yMMMMEEEEdjm; // Friday, September 20, 2019 9:50 PM

var jiffy4 = Jiffy()
    ..add(duration: Duration(days: 1, hours: 3))
    ..subtract(duration: Duration(minutes: 30));
jiffy4.format("dd/MM/yyy"); // 20/10/2019


// Months and year are added in respect to how many 
// days there are in a months and if is a year is a leap year
Jiffy("2010/1/31", "yyyy-MM-dd"); // This is January 31
Jiffy([2010, 1, 31]).add(months: 1); // This is February 28
```

Comment: Doesn't answer, how to calculate the difference in days.

Comment: Already hv mentioned that in my first example.                                                      final differenceInDays = dateTimeNow.difference(dateTimeCreatedAt).inDays;

Comment: I think you mentioned how to calculate the difference to DateTime.now(). The questions asks for difference between two dates (that are different from .now()).

Answer (score 11):

**Naively subtracting one `DateTime` from another with [`DateTime.difference`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/DateTime/difference.html) is subtly wrong.** As explained by [the `DateTime` documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/DateTime-class.html):

> The difference between two dates in different time zones is just the number of nanoseconds between the two points in time. It doesn't take calendar days into account. That means that the difference between two midnights in local time may be less than 24 hours times the number of days between them, if there is a daylight saving change in between.

Instead of rounding the computed number of days, you can ignore Daylight Saving Time in `DateTime` calculations by using **UTC** `DateTime` objects<sup>1</sup> because UTC does not observe DST.

Therefore, to compute the difference in days between two dates, ignoring the time (and also ignoring Daylight Saving adjustments and time zones), construct new UTC `DateTime` objects with the same dates and that use the same time of day:

```dart
/// Returns the number of calendar days between [later] and [earlier], ignoring
/// time of day.
///
/// Returns a positive number if [later] occurs after [earlier].
int differenceInCalendarDays(DateTime later, DateTime earlier) {
  // Normalize [DateTime] objects to UTC and to discard time information.
  later = DateTime.utc(later.year, later.month, later.day);
  earlier = DateTime.utc(earlier.year, earlier.month, earlier.day);

  return later.difference(earlier).inDays;
}
```

### Update

I've added a [`calendarDaysTill`](https://pub.dev/documentation/basics/latest/date_time_basics/DateTimeBasics/calendarDaysTill.html) extension method to [`package:basics`](https://pub.dev/packages/basics) that can do this.

---

<sup>1</sup> Be aware that *converting* a local `DateTime` object to UTC with `.toUtc()` will not help; `dateTime` and `dateTime.toUtc()` both represent the same moment in time, so `dateTime1.difference(dateTime2)` and `dateTime1.toUtc().difference(dateTime.toUtc())` would return the same `Duration`.

Answer (score 9):

You can Use the Datetime class to find the difference between the two years without using intl to format the date.

```
DateTime dob = DateTime.parse('1967-10-12');
Duration dur =  DateTime.now().difference(dob);
String differenceInYears = (dur.inDays/365).floor().toString();
return new Text(differenceInYears + ' years');
```

Comment: Doesn't handle leap years so incorrect for close dates

Answer (score 7):

If anyone wants to find out the difference in form of seconds, minutes, hours, and days. Then here is my approach.

```
static String calculateTimeDifferenceBetween(
      {@required DateTime startDate, @required DateTime endDate}) {
    int seconds = endDate.difference(startDate).inSeconds;
    if (seconds < 60)
      return '$seconds second';
    else if (seconds >= 60 && seconds < 3600)
      return '${startDate.difference(endDate).inMinutes.abs()} minute';
    else if (seconds >= 3600 && seconds < 86400)
      return '${startDate.difference(endDate).inHours} hour';
    else
      return '${startDate.difference(endDate).inDays} day';
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

```
void main() {
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.parse("2021-12-23 11:47:00");
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.parse("2018-09-12 10:57:00");

Duration diff = dt1.difference(dt2);

print(diff.inDays);
//output (in days): 1198

print(diff.inHours);
     
//output (in hours): 28752

}
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Beware of future "bugs" with selected answer

Something really missing in the selected answer - massively upvoted oddly - is that it will **calculate the difference between two dates in term of**:

> **Duration**

It means that if there is less than 24h of differences both dates will be considered to be the same!! Often it is not the desired behavior. You can fix this by tweaking slightly the code in order to truncate from the day the clock:

```
Datetime from = DateTime(1987, 07, 11); // this one does not need to be converted, in this specific example, but we assume that the time was included in the datetime.
Datetime to = DateTime.now();

print(daysElapsedSince(from, to));

[...]

int daysElapsedSince(DateTime from, DateTime to) {
// get the difference in term of days, and not just a 24h difference
  from = DateTime(from.year, from.month, from.day);  
  to = DateTime(to.year, to.month, to.day);
 
  return to.difference(from).inDays; 
}
```

You can hence detect if `from` was before `to`, as it will return a positive integer representing the difference in term of number of days, else negative, and 0 if both happened on same day.

It is indicated in the [documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/DateTime/difference.html) what this function return and in many usecases it can lead to some problem that may be difficult to debug if following the original selected answer:

> Returns a Duration with the difference when subtracting other *(from)* from this (*to*).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

## Simplest solution:

```
// d2.difference(d1).inDays

void main() {
  final d1 = DateTime.now();
  final d2 = d1.add(Duration(days: 2));
  print(d2.difference(d1).inDays);
}
```

Check it out on [DartPad example](https://dartpad.dev/?id=e031dd2e909957a564f51baeea3baadc)

Answer (score 0):

Another and maybe more intuitive option is to use Basics package:

```
 // the birthday's date
 final birthday = DateTime(1967, 10, 12);
 final today = DateTime.now();
 final difference = (today - birthday).inDays;
```

For more information about the package: https://pub.dev/packages/basics

Comment: `package:basics` now provides a [`calendarDaysTill`](https://pub.dev/documentation/basics/latest/date_time_basics/DateTimeBasics/calendarDaysTill.html) extension method that can compute the difference between two dates in terms of days.

Answer (score 0):

All of these answers miss a crucial part and that is leap year.

Here is the perfect solution for calculating age:

```
calculateAge(DateTime birthDate) {
  DateTime currentDate = DateTime.now();
  int age = currentDate.year - birthDate.year;
  int month1 = currentDate.month;
  int month2 = birthDate.month;
  if (month2 > month1) {
    age--;
  } else if (month1 == month2) {
    int day1 = currentDate.day;
    int day2 = birthDate.day;
    if (day2 > day1) {
      age--;
    }
  }
  return age;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are also correct, I just create a single method to find out the difference between the two days, accepted for the current day.

```
  void differenceBetweenDays() {
    final date1 = DateTime(2022, 01, 01); // 01 jan 2022
    final date2 = DateTime(2022, 02, 01); // 01 feb 2022
    final currentDay = DateTime.now(); // Current date
    final differenceFormTwoDates = daysDifferenceBetween(date1, date2);
    final differenceFormCurrent = daysDifferenceBetween(date1, currentDay);

    print("difference From date1 and date 2 :- "+differenceFormTwoDates.toString()+" "+"Days");
    print("difference From date1 and Today :- "+differenceFormCurrent.toString()+" "+"Days");

  }
  int daysDifferenceBetween(DateTime from, DateTime to) {
    from = DateTime(from.year, from.month, from.day);
    to = DateTime(to.year, to.month, to.day);
    return (to.difference(from).inHours / 24).round();
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

````
var start_date = "${DateTime.now()}";
var fulldate =start_date.split(" ")[0].split("-");
var year1 = int.parse(fulldate[0]);
var mon1 = int.parse(fulldate[1]);
var day1 = int.parse(fulldate[2]);
var date1 = (DateTime(year1,mon1,day1).millisecondsSinceEpoch);
var date2 = DateTime(2021,05,2).millisecondsSinceEpoch;
var Difference_In_Time = date2 - date1;
var Difference_In_Days = Difference_In_Time / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
print(Difference_In_Days); ```
````

Answer (score -2):

#### Extension on DateTime

With an `extension` class you could:

```
int days = birthdate.daysSince;
```

Example `extension` class:

```
extension DateTimeExt on DateTime {
  int get daysSince => this.difference(DateTime.now()).inDays;
}
```