# Dart/Flutter DateTime difference inDays error for March 31 April 1

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime

I am trying to get the **difference in Days between two dates** picked from a `DatePicker`. This works fine except for **ONE single date : March 31**.

The difference in Days between two `DateTimes` is wrong by 1 day when one of the dates is March 31. I know this is due to Light Saving and March is 30.9… days long and not 31, hence I am guessing, the error. But does anyone know how to fix this other than manually checking if a date is equal to March 31 and adding one day to the result ?

Two very simple examples that can be run in the [Dart Pad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/) :

```
DateTime aprilFirst = DateTime(2019, 3, 30);
DateTime marchThirtyFirst = DateTime(2019, 3, 31);

print(aprilFirst.difference(marchThirtyFirst).inDays); => -1
```

---

```
DateTime marchThirty = DateTime(2019, 4, 1);
DateTime marchThirtyFirst = DateTime(2019, 3, 31);

print(marchThirty.difference(marchThirtyFirst).inDays); => 0
```

**UPDATE**:

```
DateTime aprilFirst = DateTime(2019, 4, 1);
print(aprilFirst.add(Duration(days: -1))); => 2019-03-30 23:00:00.000
```

This should print 2019-03-31 23:00:00.000 !

I tried Günter Zöchbauer's solution of making the DateTimes UTC but the results are the exact same:

```
DateTime aprilFirst = DateTime(2019, 4, 1).toUtc();
DateTime marchThirty = DateTime(2019, 3, 30).toUtc();
DateTime marchThirtyFirst = DateTime(2019, 3, 31).toUtc();

print(aprilFirst.difference(marchThirtyFirst).inHours); => 23
print(aprilFirst.difference(marchThirtyFirst).inDays); => 0
print(marchThirty.difference(marchThirtyFirst).inHours); => -24
print(aprilFirst.add(Duration(days: -1))); => 019-03-30 22:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: and what you see if you use `inHours` instead?

Comment: @pskink There are 23 hours between March 31 and April 1. 24 hours for all the other dates.

Comment: so most likely the answer below is what you need

Comment: @pskink Sadly no. Same results

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**@Günter Zöchbauer** put me on the right path. `DateTime(...).toUTC()` will fail for difference calculations. However, using the `DateTime.utc(...)` constructor does the trick !

```
DateTime aprilFirst = DateTime.utc(2019, 4, 1);
DateTime marchThirty = DateTime.utc(2019, 3, 30);
DateTime marchThirtyFirst = DateTime.utc(2019, 3, 31);

print(aprilFirst.difference(marchThirtyFirst).inHours); => 24
print(aprilFirst.difference(marchThirtyFirst).inDays); => 1
print(marchThirty.difference(marchThirtyFirst).inHours); => -24
print(aprilFirst.add(Duration(days: -1))); => 2019-03-31 00:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: I'll be so happy when we finally eliminate DST worldwide.  It's just rediculous.

Comment: I know this is against protocol, but omg, I wasted one whole day trying to find out how this date time and daylight saving work. May the gods of bits and bytes bless you @Benjamin!

Comment: This is still a rather strange behavior. One day out of all don't work?!

Comment: @adrianvintu Did you waste a day or did you waste 23 hours?

Comment: @Rem-D hahaha, nice 1 :D

Comment: ```DateTime.utc``` litteraly saved me hours of headache

Comment: Hi there I'm having a similar problem on my question and can't figure it out 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71589896/flutter-timer-resets-when-switching-pages-with-bottom-navigation-bar

Answer (score 5):

Don't do Date comparison or operations with local dates. Convert it to UTC first. Otherwise daylight savings and other local DateTime related exceptions will cause all kinds of surprising effects.

```
DateTime aprilFirst = DateTime(2019, 3, 30).toUtc();
DateTime marchThirtyFirst = DateTime(2019, 3, 31).toUtc();

print(aprilFirst.difference(marchThirtyFirst).inDays); => -1
```

If the result is a `DateTime` you can convert it back using `xxx.toLocal()`

There is also a constructor that allows to create an UTC `DateTime` instead of creating a local `DateTime` and then converting to UTC.

Comment: Zöchbaue: I updated my question. The results are the same.

Comment: I see you figured it out \o/

Comment: *Converting* a local `DateTime` object with `.toUtc()` won't make a difference since it would still represent the same moment in time.  You would need to construct UTC `DateTime` objects with `DateTime.utc` with the desired values instead.

Comment: @jamesdlin thanks for the hint. I assumed the values come from somewhere else anyway and I just created values to demonstrate, but I agree that this can cause confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this package, [Jiffy](https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy) uses the [momentJs](https://momentjs.com/) concept of date-time difference

You can see dicussion here https://github.com/moment/moment/pull/571

```
var aprilFirst = Jiffy.parseFromList([2019, 3, 30]);
var marchThirtyFirst = Jiffy.parseFromList([2019, 3, 31]);

aprilFirst.diff(marchThirtyFirst, Unit.day); // -1

var marchThirty = Jiffy.parseFromList([2019, 4, 1]);
var marchThirtyFirst = Jiffy.parseFromList([2019, 3, 31]);

marchThirty.diff(marchThirtyFirst, Unit.day); // 1
marchThirty.diff(marchThirtyFirst, Unit.hour); // 24
marchThirty.diff(marchThirtyFirst, Unit.month; // 0
```

Answer (score 1):

#### 2021 Based on answer

```dart
extension DateCalcs on DateTime {
  DateTime get dateOnlyUTC => DateTime.utc(this.year,this.month,this.day);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already figured out that you get an unexpected result due to your locale observing Daylight Saving Time. `Duration` internally stores a number of microseconds; `Duration.days` is measured in terms of 24-hour increments and not in terms of calendar days.  From [the `DateTime` documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/DateTime-class.html):

> The difference between two dates in different time zones is just the number of nanoseconds between the two points in time. It doesn't take calendar days into account. That means that the difference between two midnights in local time may be less than 24 hours times the number of days between them, if there is a daylight saving change in between. If the difference above is calculated using Australian local time, the difference is 7415 days and 23 hours, which is only 7415 whole days as reported by `inDays`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71198806/ for a more general version of [Benjamin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55473370/) that computes the difference in days between two dates, ignoring the time (and therefore also ignoring Daylight Saving adjustments and time zones).