# Dart/Flutter duration from milliseconds

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to display a timestamp in `HH:mm:ss` in Flutter. I don't understand what how to get it working.

```
 Duration duration = new Duration(
      days: 0, hours: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: 0, milliseconds: timestamp);
  print(duration);
```

I currently get something like this:

```
flutter: 305:26:50.086000
```

Comment: `Duration duration = new Duration(milliseconds: timestamp);` why don't you just do that? what's the expected output of yours?

Comment: I think I tried that. I need HH:mm:ss

Comment: and how are you gonna do that?? you need a time from unixtime right or what? i tried your code and i get different results [here](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/0f9607ea2c72f7b6bcfbe9e78cca0bba)

Comment: I'm comparing two timestamps. One is start one is current. And I need to show how many days, hours, minutes, seconds have lapsed during the two

Comment: you could check this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52713115/flutter-finding-difference-between-two-dates

Comment: you need `Datetime` for this.. as @diegoveloper mentioned

Comment: @diegoveloper 's answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52713115/flutter-finding-difference-between-two-dates is how this should be handled.

Answer (score 12):

You can just remove the micro seconds and get it to work like this

```dart
print(duration.toString().split('.')[0]);
```