# how to get difference(remaining time ) between '22:00:00' & '00:22:00' in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to get the remaining time between `22:00:00` and `00:22:00` in Flutter.
I've tried to find the difference but it's giving me `21:38:00` but what I actually want is `02:22:00` hrs remaining.

Comment: The problem is that with hh:mm:ss timestamps there is no way for the code to know that the second timestamp is referring to a time after midnight (ie in the next day) rather than in the morning of the same day.  If you have access to the date as well as the time you could use that to compute an unambiguous result.

Comment: In the duplicate question, tooting my own, obviously biased horn, I recommend reading [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69712761/) and not reading just the top-voted/accepted answer.

Comment: i get the times from  an api  it doesnt provide date but only the times

Comment: With the time alone you won't be able to compute it correctly unless you add the date portion of it. For example, the code below gives you the correct output (if you run it on **DartPad.dev):

```flutter
var firstDate = DateTime.parse('2022-03-03T22:00:00');
var secondDate = DateTime.parse('2022-03-04T00:22:00');
  
var diff = secondDate.difference(firstDate);
print(diff);
```
You get **2:22:00.000000**, but is because you must deduct the first datetime from the current datetime (in our case, the second one you want).