# how to convert a time eg- 22:00:00 to a timestamp + include next day date in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to ask how to **convert** a given time for example  **22:00:00** into a **timestamp** and also **add** the **next day date** to it **while converting** into a time stamp in **flutter**.
**Thank You**

Comment: [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69712761/) I pointed you to in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71344083/) shows how to: 1. Parse a string that has a time. 2. How to create a `DateTime` object with it. 3. How to add a one day to that `DateTime`. Do you have specific questions about it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a Date string to a timestamp

```
 convertDateTimeToTimestamp(String yourDateTime, [Duration? extraDuration]) {
    
    DateTime date = DateTime.parse(yourDateTime);
    if (extraDuration != null) {
      date = date.add(extraDuration);
    }
    return date.microsecondsSinceEpoch;
  }
```

then your example with one additional day (next day) can be:

```dart
main() {
  final timestamp = convertDateTimeToTimestamp(
    "2022-03-05 22:00:00",
    Duration(days: 1),
  );
  print(timestamp); //output: 1646600400000000
  
  // try to check the converted timestamp with addition duration in the example above, it's only one day
  DateTime date = DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp);
  print('${date.year}-${date.month}-${date.day} ${date.hour}:${date.minute}:${date.second}'); //output: 2022-3-6 22:0:0
}
```

you can use `intl` package and format your `datetime` easier.

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp data type is defined in cloud_firestore.

What do you mean by timestamp?