# Create Timer With Given Data

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have an app which gets hours and minutes from the backend. Every time the app is called the data from the backend gets saved in shared preferences. When he user has no internet connection I show the same screen as the user saw when having internet just using the data saved in shared preferences instead. One of the parts of the data is a timer which I get the hours and minutes from the backend, and the hours and minutes get updated every time I make the API call. What I want now is to have the data from shared preferences to create a timer with the data saved in shared preferences. I need to have the minutes and hours update and work just like it would with the normal data with internet connection. So when there is no internet connection we display the data and I need to create the timer to update the minutes and the hours so the user can see the timer update even when there is no internet. So if the minutes and hours in shared preferences are saved like: 1hr : 6mins. I need to make it so the time keeps going and minutes and hours keep updating. So after 60 secs mins will be 7mins, and after 54mins hours will be 2hrs, And the process starts right when the screen is opened without any start button.

```
// Saving data from api in shared preferences

 body: FutureBuilder<Response>(
        future: futureDataForStatus,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
              snapshot.hasData) {
            accountInfo = WorkingLocationStatus.fromJson(
              json.decode(snapshot.data!.body),
            );

            final duration = IsoDuration.parse(
              accountInfo!.duration.toString(),
            );

            prefs.setDouble('workingHours', duration.hours);
            prefs.setDouble('workingMinutes', duration.minutes);

            return Column(

   // Displaying the saved data 

class OffilneWorkingHoursMinutes extends StatefulWidget {
  const OffilneWorkingHoursMinutes({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<OffilneWorkingHoursMinutes> createState() =>
      _OffilneWorkingHoursMinutesState();
}

class _OffilneWorkingHoursMinutesState
    extends State<OffilneWorkingHoursMinutes> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text(
        '${prefs.getDouble('workingHours')!.toStringAsFixed(0)} hrs - '
        '${prefs.getDouble('workingMinutes')!.toStringAsFixed(0)} mins ',
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to be more concise and precise. I read your question, but didn't really get what your problem is.

Comment: sorry for the last of good explaination but the problem is that i need to make the app so it gets the data from the prefs and keep updating the minutes and hours without having to press start button so right when the screen opens the minutes and hours need to be incremented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this example, I think it could help, just adjust it to your needs:

```
class OffilneWorkingHoursMinutes extends StatefulWidget {
  const OffilneWorkingHoursMinutes({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<OffilneWorkingHoursMinutes> createState() =>
      _OffilneWorkingHoursMinutesState();
}

class _OffilneWorkingHoursMinutesState
    extends State<OffilneWorkingHoursMinutes> {
  var time = Time(hours: 1, minutes: 6, seconds: 0); // pass your time from backend here
  @override
  void initState() {
    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) { // use timer when you are offline and cancel it when you are back online
      setState(() {
        if (time.seconds < 59) {
          time.seconds++;
        } else {
          if (time.minutes < 59) {
            time.minutes++;
          } else {
            time.minutes = 0;
            time.hours++;
          }
          time.seconds = 0;
        }
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text(
        '${time.hours} hrs - '
        '${time.minutes} mins - '
        '${time.seconds} sec ',
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Time {
  int hours;
  int minutes;
  int seconds;
  Time({
    this.hours = 0,
    this.minutes = 0,
    this.seconds = 0,
  });
}
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way for this to work even if the app is closed

Comment: For other parts of the app i use AppLifecycleState

Comment: There should be a way but I haven't worked with background processes yet, so I'm not suitable to give you an advice it that area. You should try to find something for background processes in flutter. Good luck ;)