# how to find difference btw 21:00 pm - 1:00 am in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication

can someone please humbly help me? im fining it extremely confusing.

the dates are like this

1st date ~ 2 May 21:00
2nd date ~ 3 May 04:00

Comment: If you already have two `DateTime` objects, you can use [`DateTime.difference`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/DateTime/difference.html).  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69712761/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we have two dates.

```
var d1 = '2 May 04:00';
var d2 = '3 May 05:00';
```

First, add this [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl/install) package to your project and import it

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

Next, you need to set a dateformat for your dates above:

```
var dFormat = DateFormat('d MMM HH:mm');
```

The date format should be same as your dates orelse you will get an error.

Next, convert the datetime string to your desired format.

```
var dateTime1 = dFormat.parse(d1, true);
var dateTime2 = dFormat.parse(d2, true);
```

You can set true if you want UTC time.

Lastly, to get difference between two dates just do the following:

```
print(dateTime2.difference(dateTime1).inHours); //25
```

The above print statement will return `25` as the difference between both the given time is 25hours. You can get difference in Minutes too.

Happy Coding!