# how to subtract two different times in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, data-structures, time

I want to subtract two different times in flutter for example

```
String time1 = "07:00";
String time2 = "08:12";

String time3 = time2 - time1;
//result will be 01:12
```

this is just a sample data explanation of what I want to achieve.

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/70020886/11404883

Comment: @AamilSilawat that solution returning hours and seconds separately but i want the exact result as mentioned above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the sample code below. It prints 01:12 in the end.

But as was pointed out in the comments below, this only works if `time2` is greater or equal to `time1`.

Input Data:

```
String time1 = "07:00";
String time2 = "08:12";
```

Required Methods to be defined:

```
DateTime getTime(final String inputString) => DateFormat("hh:mm").parse(inputString);

String getString(final Duration duration) {
  String formatDigits(int n) => n.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
  final String minutes = formatDigits(duration.inMinutes.remainder(60));
  return "${formatDigits(duration.inHours)}:$minutes";
}
```

Computation

```
final String difference = getString(getTime(time2).difference(getTime(time1)));
```

Printing the result

```
print(difference); // 01:12
```

Have fun - but keep in mind to change the naming of the methods to better fit into your context.

Comment: answer accepted for a better explanation⭐️

Comment: Hi @BorisBaroslav i found an error in subtracting.  From time is 11:57 and To time is 12:30
Work hours should display 00:33, but display -10 : -57

Comment: this is only happening when either from or to time has 12 0 clock

Answer (score 1):

Flutter|Dart provides a data type to handle dates : [DateTime](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html). So instead of using String, use DateTime :

```
DateTime time1 = DateTime.parse(your_date_here your_time);
DateTime time2 = DateTime.parse(your_date_here your_time);
DateTime time3 = time2.difference(time1);
```

If you want just the time part, you can format it using DateFormat from the [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package. You'll need to import it as follows :

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

Then do the following:

```
String formattedTime = DateFormat.Hms().format(time1);
String formattedTime = DateFormat.Hms().format(time2);
```

Or you can just directly format the result (time3):

```
String formattedTime = DateFormat.Hms().format(time3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Dart's built-in `DateTime` class and its `DateTime.parse` especially.

Documentation: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html

Answer (score 0):

**Try out below code** for get difference between two times.

```html
    var timeFormat = DateFormat("HH:mm"); //Time format
    var first = timeFormat.parse("10:40");
    var second = timeFormat.parse("18:20");
    print("Difference -->${second.difference(first)}");
    // prints Difference -->7:40
```

Comment: your answer is also a right dude.

Comment: I already accepted answer of Boris as his answer fits my context and work like a charm in my project