# How to check if current date and time falls between two given date and time in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the below info:

```
final startDateTime = DateTime(2020, 7, 6, 18, 00);
final endDateTime = DateTime(2020, 7, 7, 19, 00);
final currentDateTime = DateTime.now();
```

How do I find if currentDateTime is between startDateTime and endDateTime.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: Finding Difference Between Two Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52713115/flutter-finding-difference-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define a method:

```dart
bool isCurrentDateInRange(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) {
  final currentDate = DateTime.now();
  return currentDate.isAfter(startDate) && currentDate.isBefore(endDate);
}
```

Use it like:

```
var isDateInRange = isCurrentDateInRange(startDate, endDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

```dart
if (currentDateTime.isAfter(startDateTime) && currentDateTime.isBefore(endDateTime)) {
    ...
}
```