# How to work with listviews correctly for displaying text

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I'm trying to display an message, but unfortunately I think I'll need to change my method.

So I've resumed some code

```
                      child: FutureBuilder<List<Product>>(
                          future: products,
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                              return const Center(
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                              );
                            }

                            final products = snapshot.data!;
                            return Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                child: ListView.builder(
                                    itemCount: products.length, // currently has 400 items
                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                      if (difference == 0) {
                                        return cardUI(
                                ...
                                        );
                                      } else {
                                        return Text('Nothing to display!');
                                      }
                                    }));
                          })),
```

How can I manage to return the message only one time? Do I need to change all the code? Since it's displaying almost 250 times 'Nothing to display'

Edit:
This is what I'm using to calculate the difference!

```
                                    DateTime productExpire = DateTime.parse(products[index].date);

                                     
                                      final productDate = productExpire;
                                      final today = DateTime.now();
                                      final difference = calcDays(
                                          today, productDate);
```

Comment: what is `difference` in your case

Comment: it's a simple function that I have to calculate the difference between dates, I resumed some code so It could fit here the basic

Comment: Does this method use any property from product? What is the relation between product and this difference

Comment: Basicly it's getting the product date, and calculating the days between the product date and today. Only show the product if the difference of days == 0. Resumed only showing products that the date are equal to today.

Comment: on `itemCount` you can filter this data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that comes to mind is to make products only equal to the products that have a difference of days from today of zero, so then based on `products.length` you can either return a `Text()` (`if products.length == 0`) or call `ListView.builder` (`if products.length > 0`).

**Basically:**

Instead of this:

> **All products**
>
> products = [thisProdHasDifferenceOfZero, thisOneDoesnt, thisOneDoes, thisOneDoesnt, ...]
>
> (products.length == 400 every time)

You can just have:

> **Only products that you want to work with**
>
> products = [thisProdHasDiffOfZero, thisOneToo, thisOneToo, ...]
>
> (products.length <= 400)

**In your code:**

Instead of calculating the difference your way, use this:

> This method calculates the difference between two dates, the one you're using may run into some bugs... [check this answer for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67679455/14104020)

```dart
    int daysBetween(DateTime from, DateTime to) {
        from = DateTime(from.year, from.month, from.day);
        to = DateTime(to.year, to.month, to.day);
        return (to.difference(from).inHours / 24).round();
    }
```

Then:

```dart
    child: FutureBuilder<List<Product>>(
        future: products,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
        }
        final today = DateTime.now();
        final products = (snapshot.data! as List<Product>).where((product) => daysBetween(product.date, today) == 0).toList;
         // Now you know that every product inside 'products', if there's any, has a day difference of 0.
        return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        // 'products' can be empty since you may have 0 products that have the difference you are looking for.
        // In that case you return the text.
        child: (products.length == 0) ? 
            return Text('Nothing to display!');
            : return ListView.builder( // If products has one or more items...
                 itemCount: products.length,
                 itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                     return cardUI(
                         ...
                     );
                  }
              )
         ...
```

Comment: Hi, I've updated a little bit more, since i'm using products[index].date

Comment: Hello @Miguel I've updated my answer. I think this should work just fine. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi @darth_dever sorry to be such a pain in the ass, I have one more little problem x), the dates are string, so I was converting the date before comparing. I tried a lot of things with your code, but couldnt do nothing. I should learn more flutter. Thanks anyway :/

Comment: I've tried daysBetween(DateTime.parse(product.date), today) == 0).toList; withou success

Comment: Hi @Miguel no problem at all! Personally I think that you should not store the product date as a `String` since it can limit you to to various things or even make it harder, you should store the date as `DateTime`... then if you want to display the product date in a `Text()`, you can always use various formatters included with dart or [outside packages like this one](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) :)

Comment: Hi again @darth_dever . Yes I know! But since I'm using google sheets as a simple db this is the best way, since they can edit into the sheet itself and not only using the app, that's why I choose this way! Thanks one more time!

Answer (score 0):

You want to show a single error if the listview.builder does not have any data right? Hope I am not getting you wrong. If so you can use the ternary operator where you have mentioned the listview.builder to make it conditional.

or you can try to update the item count with condition.

```
itemcount: difference ==0? products.length : 1,
```

Answer (score 0):

After getting all products filter them and create another list of product that will satisfy difference==0.

```dart
 final products = snapshot.data!;
 
 List<Product> temp = [];
 // temp = products.where((p) => validation(p) == 0).toList();

 for(final p in products)
   {
     int difference = yourValidation(p);
     if(difference == 0) temp.add(p);
   }

   //...
   child: ListView.builder(
     itemCount: temp.length,
```

More about [`List`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-core/List-class.html)

Comment: *this* I managed to work out, but the struggling with printing 'no products available' still persists !

Comment: Hi, I've updated a little bit more, since i'm using products[index].date

Comment: now you can use `temp[index]`