# how to get differece of two dates ignoring year in dart?

Tags: flutter

I am creating ann app where a widget showing next birthday in days
like

```
final date1=DateTime(1980,12,25);
final date2=DateTime(2023,12,21);

date1 difference with today is 2 days
date2 difference with today is 361 days..(near abt)
```

i know date method 'difference' but it calculate year also,

here i want to ignore year

i have tried my way but looking not good code

```
int dateDifference(DateTime date) {
    
    final today = DateTime.now();
//here replacing date's year with current year
    DateTime dummyDate=DateTime(DateTime.now().year,date.month,date.day);
    int difference = 0;

    if (dummyDate.isBefore(today)) {
      print('Yes it is before today');
//adding one year 
      dummyDate = DateTime(DateTime.now().year+1 , dummyDate.month, dummyDate.day);

      difference = dummyDate.difference(today).inDays;
    } else {

      difference = dummyDate.difference(today).inDays;
    }
    return difference;
  }
```

Comment: Leap year makes this an incomplete spec.  Do you count a feb 29?  If so, when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't just ignore the year.  The number of days between two dates depends on the year; there is 1 day between February 28 and March 1 for 2023, but there are 2 days between them 2024.
2. Using `DateTime.difference().inDays` naively will give you unexpected results for locales that observe Daylight Saving Time if there is a DST event during that timespan.  Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71198806/

If you want to compute the number of days until someone's next birthday, what you have is already mostly right, but you should perform computations with UTC `DateTime` objects to avoid DST problems, and you could do some refactoring to avoid code duplication:

```dart
int daysTill(int month, int day) {
  var now = DateTime.now();

  // Discard time information.
  //
  // Also Perform all computations with UTC Datetime objets to avoid DST effects.
  var today = DateTime.utc(now.year, now.month, now.day);
  var next = DateTime.utc(today.year, month, day);

  if (next.isBefore(today)) {
    next = next.copyWith(year: today.year + 1);
  }

  return next.difference(today).inDays;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check updated code that calculates the number of days until the next occurrence of a specific month and day, by comparing today's date with the target date set to the current year, and adjusting to the next year if it has already passed.

```
   int dateDifference(DateTime date) {
      final today = DateTime.now();
      DateTime targetDate = DateTime(today.year, date.month, date.day);

      if (targetDate.isBefore(today)) {
        targetDate = DateTime(today.year + 1, date.month, date.day);
      }
    
      return targetDate.difference(today).inDays;
    }
```