# how to fetch upcoming dates from list of event in dart

Tags: flutter

I have created a birthday reminder app where i have data like events..

Now i want to show upcoming birthday with sorting and want to show on listview builder

```
void main() {


  List<EventModel> events = [
  EventModel(
    title: 'A',
    date: DateTime(1980, 08, 12),
  ),
  EventModel(
  title: 'Z',
  date: DateTime(2020, 12, 28),
  ),
  EventModel(
  title: 'B',
  date: DateTime(1995, 12, 21),
  ),
];
   events.sort((a, b) => (a.date).compareTo(b.date));

   for(var x in events)
     print(x.date.toString());



}
```

above code giving me output  as it is sorting entire date including year..how to sort based on month and day only..

```
1980-08-12 00:00:00.000
1995-12-21 00:00:00.000
2020-12-28 00:00:00.000
```

I need following output as upcoming birthday is like

```
2020-12-28 00:00:00.000
1980-08-12 00:00:00.000
1995-12-21 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: You can use the techniques I showed you [in your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77700353/) to replace the years with the current year when performing comparisons.  Or have your comparison function just directly compare months and days, just as you would do when [sorting by multiple keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61673246/).

Comment: right but confuse how to implement my code..i was to count days...it was done..but now how to show on listview builder with sorted list....cant solve

Comment: For example: `DateTime.utc(currentYear, a.year, a.month).compareTo(DateTime.utc(currentYear, b.year, b.month))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check comments of @jamesdlin its useful to solve ur problem

i have created a method named ignoreYear which return a date ignoring year and it will check whether date is before or after of today date...

here is your solution..

you might get some expert code but here is basic code...

```
DateTime ignoreYear(DateTime date) {
  final now = DateTime.now();
  var today = DateTime.utc(now.year, now.month, now.day);
  var next = DateTime.utc(today.year, date.month, date.day);

  if (next.isBefore(today)) {
    next = next.copyWith(year: today.year + 1);
  }
  return next;
}

void main() {
  events.sort((a, b) => ignoreYear(a.date).compareTo(ignoreYear(b.date)));

  for (var x in events) print(x.date.toString());
}
```

All credit goes to **jamesdlin**

Answer (score 2):

I think you can achieve your goals by simply writing a custom comparator that only compares the months and days.

```dart
int Function(DateTime, DateTime) createCompartor(DateTime referenceDate) {
  int compareDates(DateTime a, DateTime b) {
    // factorA and factorB are 1 when the date (birthday) is next year. 
    final factorA = a.copyWith(year: referenceDate.year).isAfter(referenceDate) ? 0 : 1;
    final factorB = b.copyWith(year: referenceDate.year).isAfter(referenceDate) ? 0 : 1;
    
    // Using factorA and factorB, we create new dates where birthdays that
    // are in the next year are larger than the birthdays that are in this
    // remaining year.
    return a.copyWith(year: referenceDate.year + factorA).compareTo(b.copyWith(year: referenceDate.year + factorB));
  }
  
  return compareDates;
}

void main() {


  List<DateTime> events = [
    DateTime(2023, 8, 8),
    DateTime(2002, 11, 11),
    DateTime(1990, 12, 29),
    DateTime(2023, 1, 1),
    DateTime(2020, 12, 28),
  ];
  
  events.sort(createCompartor(DateTime.now()));

  for(var x in events)
    print(x.toString());
}
```

Outputs

```
2020-12-28 00:00:00.000
1990-12-29 00:00:00.000
2023-01-01 00:00:00.000
2023-08-08 00:00:00.000
2002-11-11 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: This is not i want dear....first upcoming date should be  2020-12-28 and 2nd  1990-12-29 and 3rd 2023-01-01..think about upcoming birthday

Comment: @IMemon I've updated the answer based on your comment.